# Child stylesheet not enqueuing

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to enqueue my child stylesheet within functions.php. The parent stylesheet is working as it should, but none of the changes I make within the child stylesheet are working.
Code is as below. Any help, muchly appreciated

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'popper-style';

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'popper-child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

Comment: What does the header of your child theme look like?  Please add that to your question.

Comment: I don't have one at the moment. Just style.css and functions.php file

Comment: That's part of the problem then.  It won't work if the header isn't right.  Read the docs for details.

Comment: It's just that I'm following a course and we haven't got to that yet. But when he tests his child css, it works, but not for me